# svn diff suddenly not showing anything, even though svn status shows modified files

Tags: centos, svn, diff

I made some changes to a local, up-to-date repo, on CentOS 7, svn 1.7.14.

Running `svn diff` shows the changes.

Not sure if this has much to do with it, but a while later, I did an `svn copy` over to a new branch.

Then I made a change.

Now running `svn status` shows the change as a file with an M beside it, but `svn diff` shows nothing, even if I specify the exact file with the M.

Is this correct behaviour?  I expected it to show the diff...

## Update

I also re-installed subversion via `yum reinstall`, and the result is no different.

## Update 2

I made a second change (the first change was with `sed`, this was with `vim`) and now the diff shows just that change, as if the first change were the starting point.  But I never committed the first change--if I go to the online repo viewer I can see that the latest revision shows before both changes.  This new `diff` output says `rev 609` vs `working copy`, but `609` is the latest one in the viewer.  How do I have a different `609` than the online one?

## Update 3

Even though `svn up` shows `At revision 609`, `svn log --limit 2` shows revs `607` and `605`.  Do I have local repo corruption?  If so it happened very soon after a successful checkout...or does it have to do with the `svn copy`?  `svn info` shows the original `trunk`, not the branch I copied to...

Answer (score 1):

I had piped `grep` results into `sed` but the `grep` syntax had been incorrect, with `--exclude-dir='*/.svn'` instead of `--exclude-dir='.svn'`.  Thus the changes were made in the `.svn` directories too, corrupting the repo.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Just started using sed for refactoring, exact same anomaly seen, sure enough I have allowed sed to change files in .svn. Oops!